# Extracting next line of text file

Tags: python, string, file

I am trying to extract specific information from a .txt file. I have figured out a way to isolate the lines I need; however, printing them has proven to be problematic.

```
with open('RCSV.txt','r') as RCSV:
   for line in RCSV.read().splitlines():
      if line.startswith('   THETA'):
           print(line.next())
```

When I use `line.next()` it gives me this error:

```
"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'next'"
```

[Here is a link to the .txt file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hi01j9v6a69o2zr/RCSV.txt?dl=0)
[Here is a link to the area of the file in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X34I6.jpg)

What I'm trying to do is extract the line following the line that starts with 'THETA PHI' etc.

Comment: `RCSV.read().splitlines()` returns a list of lines.

Comment: You can't call `line.next()`, not just because strings don't have a `next` method, but because strings are just strings; they don't know that they came out of an iterator. The thing you want to call `next` on is the iterator. If you just iterated directly over the file (instead of reading the whole file into memory and then splitting it into lines and storing them all in a list just to get the same lines the file would have already given you), `next(RCSV)` would do that. Although I'm not sure it's actually what you want (it usually isn't).

Comment: I answered a very closely related question yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599623/python-search-string-from-output-variable-and-print-next-two-lines/49599785#49599785

Answer (score 1):

you could use `next(input)`, as:

```
with open('RCSV.txt', "r") as input:
    for line in input:
        if line.startswith('   THETA'):
           print(next(input), end='')
           break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag to get all lines after you find the key.

**Ex:**

```
with open('RCSV.txt','r') as RCSV:
    content = RCSV.readlines()
    flag = False                         #Check Flag
    for line in content:
        if not flag:
            if line.startswith('   THETA'):
                flag = True
        else:
            print(line)                  #Prints all lines after '   THETA'
```

Or if you need just the following line.

```
with open('RCSV.txt','r') as RCSV:
    for line in RCSV:
        if line.startswith('   THETA'):
            print(next(RCSV))
```

Comment: Are you sure `next(RCSV)` its working ?

Comment: Yes, its working in Python2.7 & 3.5

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
with open('RCSV.txt','r') as RCSV:
    for line in RCSV:
        if line.startswith('   THETA'):
            next_line = RCSV.readline() # or RCSV.next()
            print(next_line)
```

Note that on your next iteration, `line` will be the line after `next_line`.

Comment: It didn't seem to work. It provided me with no output.

Comment: @Mike could you post an example file?

Answer (score 0):

String object has no attribute next, next is an attribute of file object. so fileobject.next() returns the next line i.e. RCSV.next().